# why we are getting "JVM error 104" error?

Tags: blackberry

I am getting "JVM error 104" error message, when I try to run my Blackberry application.

If I add the following statements, I am getting the issue. All classes are `MainScreen`.

```
1.) Ui.getUiEngine().pushScreen(new SubCardSelection());
```

```
2.) Dialog.alert("Welcome");
```

My question is; Why I am getting this error message ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because:

- you forget to set the right style (`ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK`) as in [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Dialog-Inform-throws-error-when-used-from-within-change-listener/m-p/607000)

```
ButtonField searchButton = new ButtonField( "Search" , ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK | ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER );
searchButton.setChangeListener( new FieldChangeListener(){
    public void fieldChanged( Field field , int context){
        Dialog.alert( "Pressed Search" );
    }
});
```

- or just because you don't consume the events in the right place (as [explained here](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/226218-need-some-help-buttons.html)):

> You are adding some fields to the screen in the constructor (correct), then attempting to retrieve the values from the fields in the same constructor (incorrect).
>   The fields will not even be displayed to the user until you exit the constructor and allow the framework to display the screen.

Any way, that ends with a runtime uncaught exception, which is what "`JVM error 104`" means.

Comment: I written the code like follows; private FocusChangeListener focusChange = new FocusChangeListener() { public void focusChanged(Field field, int context) { Ui.getUiEngine().pushScreen(new SubCardSelection()); } };